# Android list not loading from sqlite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, csv

I've been working on an Android app that uses a database to populate a list. The database is filled with records from a .csv file that is located in the /assets folder. Everything was working a few minutes ago, but ever since I've refreshed my CSV, the list with data is not being shown anymore (it is just saying "No orders to display", which means that it didn't find any data to populate the list with). Furthermore, the code produces no errors and the LogCat is not really being useful te me.

I wonder if anyone could help me: you have my thanks!

This is the DatabaseActivity.java file:

```
public class DatabaseActivity extends ListActivity {

String ID;
String title;
String location;
String startTime;
String endTime;
String date;
String description;
private DatabaseHelper dbh;

private ProgressDialog m_ProgressDialog = null; 
private ArrayList<Order> m_orders = null;
private OrderAdapter m_adapter;
private Runnable viewOrders;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    this.dbh = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    try {
        csvtodb();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    m_orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
    this.m_adapter = new OrderAdapter(this, R.layout.row, m_orders);
    setListAdapter(this.m_adapter);

    viewOrders = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getOrders();
        }
    };
    Thread thread =  new Thread(null, viewOrders, "MagentoBackground");
    thread.start();
    m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(DatabaseActivity.this,    
            "Even geduld...", "Database wordt geladen...", true);

}

private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(m_orders != null && m_orders.size() > 0){
            m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            for(int i=0;i<m_orders.size();i++)
                m_adapter.add(m_orders.get(i));
        }
        m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
        m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};

private void getOrders(){
    try{
        m_orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.query(DatabaseHelper.tblEvents, 
                new String[] {DatabaseHelper.title, 
                DatabaseHelper.location, 
                DatabaseHelper.startTime,
                DatabaseHelper.description}, 
                null, null, null, null, 
                DatabaseHelper.startTime + " ASC");
        int numberOfRows = c.getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++){
            c.moveToPosition(i);
            // Obtain the title
            int col1 = c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.title);
            String title = c.getString(col1);
            // Obtain the location
            int col2 = c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.location);
            String location = c.getString(col2);
            // Obtain the time
            int col3 = c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.startTime);
            String startTime = c.getString(col3);
            // Obtain the description
            int col4 = c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.description);
            String description = c.getString(col4);
            Order o = new Order();
            o.setOrderTime(startTime);
            o.setOrderTitle(title);
            o.setOrderLocation(location);
            o.setOrderDescription(description);
            m_orders.add(o);
        }
        db.close();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        Log.i("ARRAY", ""+ m_orders.size());
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        Log.e("BACKGROUND_PROC", e.getMessage());
    }
    runOnUiThread(returnRes);
}



public void csvtodb() throws IOException {
    // Get a writable database
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getWritableDatabase();
    if (dbh.isDbInitialized(db)) {
        db.close();
        return;
    }

    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream input = assetManager.open("testcsv.csv");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
    String reader = "";
    while ((reader = in.readLine()) != null)
    {
        String[] RowData = reader.split(",");

        ID = RowData[0];
        title = RowData[1];
        location = RowData[2];
        startTime = RowData[3];
        endTime = RowData[4];
        date = RowData[5];
        description = RowData[6];

        DatabaseHelper.fillTable(db, ID, title, location, startTime, endTime, date, description);
    }

    in.close();
}

public class OrderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Order> {

    private ArrayList<Order> items;

    public OrderAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Order> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }
        Order o = items.get(position);
        if (o != null) {
            TextView time = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time);
            TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
            TextView location = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.location);
            TextView description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);
            if (time != null) {
                time.setText(o.getOrderTime());                            
            }
            if(title != null){
                title.setText(o.getOrderTitle());
            }
            if(location != null){
                location.setText("Locatie: " + o.getOrderLocation());
            }
            if(description != null){
                description.setText(o.getOrderDescription());
            }
        }
        return v;
    }
}
}
```

And here is the DatabaseHelper.java:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
// Database name and version
static final String dbName = "Evenementen";
static final int dbVersion = 1;

// Names of tables and columns
static final String tblEvents = "Evenementen";
static final String eventID = "ID";
static final String title = "Titel";
static final String location = "Locatie";
static final String startTime = "Begintijd";
static final String endTime = "Eindtijd";
static final String date = "Datum";
static final String description = "Beschrijving";


// Constructor
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, dbName, null, dbVersion);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    createDB(db);
}

public void createDB(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + tblEvents + " (" +
            eventID   + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            title   + " TEXT , " +
            location   + " TEXT , " +
            startTime   + " TEXT , " +
            endTime   + " TEXT , " +
            date   + " TEXT , " +
            description + " TEXT" +
            ")");
}

public boolean isDbInitialized(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    return db.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT tbl_name FROM sqlite_master WHERE tbl_name = '"+ tblEvents + "'", null) != null;
}

public static void fillTable(SQLiteDatabase db, String first, String second, String third, 
        String fourth, String fifth, String sixth, String seventh) {
    String template = "INSERT INTO " + tblEvents + 
            "(" + eventID + "," + title + "," + location + "," + startTime + "," + endTime + "," + date + "," + description + ")" + 
            "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    Object[] args = new Object[]{first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth, seventh};
    db.execSQL(template, args);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Bluntly remove table (and thus discard ALL data in it!) if we're upgrading  
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tblEvents);
    onCreate(db);
}

}
```

This is my CSV file (it's Dutch. The values are seperated by comma):

```
1,Cross Rubicon,van der Werff & Studio de Veste,15:00,Nvt,03-okt,Geen beschrijving beschikbaar
2,Ferry Nick & Lodewijk Band,van der Werff & Studio de Veste,18:30,Nvt,03-okt,Bekend van de Edwin Evers Band & Marco Borsato
3,LOS,van der Werff & Studio de Veste,21:00,Nvt,03-okt,Nederpopcovers
4,La Cubaniza,Scheltema,16:00,Nvt,03-okt,Cuban liveband & DJ
```

FYI: I'm using [this reference](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) for displaying my data from the database in a list.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your activity finds column by title

```
// Obtain the time
            int col1 = c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.title);
```

But the CSV listing included doesn't have titles...

Comment: The CSV only provides the data for the columns of my database. In the DatabaseHelper.java, 7 columns are defined for the 7 records in the CSV file:
1 -> ID, 2 -> title, 3 -> location, 4 -> startTime, 5 -> endTime, 6 ->date, 7 -> description